# chap links library - network- how to get table row id

Tags: javascript, plugins, chap-links-library

I'm using chap links library https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library/tree/master/js/src/network for drawing an area of objects.

I want to be able to use the id that I have set to an object upon click, I have this code

```
    function onselect() {
        var sel = network.getSelection();
        console.log("selected "+sel[0].row);
    }
```

It works fine, only it retrieves the row number from the dynamically created table. I want to retrieve a value from that row (an object id that I set) but I don't know how to access it.

I have tired things like

sel[0].row.id

sel[0].row.getId()

sel[0].row[0]

But I don't know how they structure the data in their thing...

Anyonw run into this before and solved it?

This is the way I set the data

```
            nodesTable.addRow([45, "myObjectName", "image", "images/container_icons/icon.png"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my app I solved it by creating a parallel array...

```
    //rendera objekt
    window.clickHelper = []; //keep track of container id in conjunction with hierarchy-canvas-object's id
    var i = 0; //counter for above
```

Populating it upon every node creation...

```
            nodesTable.addRow([{{ c.id }}, "{{ c.name }}", "image", "{{ asset('images/container_icons/'~c.icon~'.png') }}"]);
            clickHelper[i]={{c.id}};
            i++;
```

Then calling in data from that array on my onSelect event...

```
    function onselect() {
        //get selected node from network
        var sel = network.getSelection();
        sel = sel[0].row;

        //get path base structure
        var path = '{{ path('editGroup') }}';

        //fix path with the DB id of the clicked object
        path = path+clickHelper[sel];

        window.location.href = path;
    }
```

The double {{ }} are TWIG templating for those unfamiliar with that. Mixed javascript and TWIG ServerSide code here, sorry.